# EJS module not found on OpenShift NodeJS template

Tags: node.js, ejs, openshift

I am unable to use EJS as my view render engine on NodeJS.

I have found several similar questions but all state about installing EJS that really work for others. This is not same for me, may be because I am unable to choose the right directory (among so many duplicates in OpenShift repo) for the installation.

I have NodeJS default app created by OpenShift template. While installing EJS dependency I somehow screwed it and I get following error (standard NodeJS  error for unavailable module):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at View.templateEngine (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view/view.js:134:38)
    at Function.compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:68:17)
    at ServerResponse._render (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:318:17)
    at /var/lib/openshift/5123c2494382ec16ca000222/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:114:17
    at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
```

Besides mentioning in package.json, I tried installing ejs through terminal at app-root, runtime and nodejs-0.6 level as well (and restarting of the app), but of no use.

My directory structure is:

```
-app-root
---data
---repo
-----node_modules (has ejs)
-----server.js
-----package.json ("dependencies": {"ejs" : ">=0.8.3"},)
-----views
-------defaultError.ejs
---runtime
-----data
-----node_modules (empty)
-----repo (identical to app-root/repo)
-------node_modules (has ejs)
-nodejs-0.6
---data
---repo (identical to app-root/repo)
-----node_modules (has ejs)
---runtime
-----node_modules (empty)
-----repo (identical)
-------node_modules (has ejs)
```

defaultError.ejs is just plain html.
server.js has following:

```
self.createRoutes = function() {
        self.routes = { };

        //...
        self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
        };

        self.routes['/helloejs'] = function(req, res){
            res.render('defaultError', { layout:false } );
        };
    };

self.initializeServer = function() {
        self.createRoutes();
        self.app = express.createServer();

        self.app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };
```

Hope this long post makes my problem clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to using incorrect directory. You have to install packages and run your application from your project directory. Here is the directory structure of the folder i use as a project.

```
.
├── app.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── express
│   ├── jade
│   └── socket.io
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
├── server.js
└── views
    └── layout.jade
```

Using `npm install` from this folder adds package folder within the node_modules sub folder (like `express`, `socket.io`). You should use `node` from this location, as all locally installed modules are visible from this folder only.

Comment: The directory structure that I mentioned is maintained by OpenShift platform so that it could manage the build/deploy cycle in it its standard way. As I can see that structure resembles to the one from yours as well. Though there are a lot of duplicate "repo/" directories here that I am lost. I also tried installing ejs directory "app-root/runtime/" and "app-root/runtime/repo" (directory mentioned in the original error trace).

Comment: I am not sure the exact cause, but this is how my issue vanished: I added 'express' in the package.json. This is very strange as a default installation of express is avaiable for all apps on OpenShift. Marking the above answer correct as it at least provides a necessary checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I just added ejs manually in **package.json**:

```
 {
   "name": "myApp"
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.12.2",
     "ejs": "^1.0.0"
   }
 }
```

And run **npm install** (may be you need run it with **sudo**)
Please note, that ejs looks views directory by default

Answer (score 0):

when install ejs you must use option --save:

```
npm install ejs --save
```

and create .gitignore file:

```
node_modules
```